# What is the difference between "Message Digest" and Checksum?

Tags: security, checksum

As far as I understand Message Digest is a certain Hash function that is derived from the original payload, so that even if a single bit changes the Message Digest proves to be different, thus indicating a failure of data integrity.
When it comes to Checksum, I know that it is used for error detection, and is based on a similar mechanism.

What is the difference? Why name two different things?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A checksum is the general term used. A checksum can range from a check digit (parity bit) to a complex output string. Different checksums (examples below) can be chosen depending on the application.

- message digest
- hash algorithm
- digital fingerprint
- randomization function